# how to rotate canvas context so that it fully fits the canvas area?

Tags: html, canvas, rotation

This is a bit lame question, as I am new to canvas. I need to rotate an image that I placed inside a canvas **so that it fully fits in the canvas area**. In the code snippet given below the image is rotated fine, but I don't know how to make it fit the canvas rectangle. I can try to use mathematical approach with trigonometry, but I think it's too complex :)

[image: rotating context to fit canvas area]
<sub>(source: [iconizer.net](http://iconizer.net/img/temp/how-to-rotate.jpg))</sub>

```
var imgObj=new Image();
imgObj.src='people.jpg';
var width=128;//dynamic
var height=128;//dynamic


$(imgObj).load(function() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var rad = 30 * Math.PI / 180;

    context.translate(0 + width / 2, 0 + height / 2);

    context.rotate(rad);

    //draw the image    
    context.drawImage(imgObj,width / 2 * (-1),height / 2 * (-1),width,height);

    //reset the canvas  
    context.rotate(rad * ( -1 ) );
    context.translate((0 + width / 2) * (-1), (0 + height / 2) * (-1));
});
```

It was very easy to do in PHP through simply placing the rotated image with desired coordinates, but in canvas it's not the case. Please, help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem myself. Though, it's a little complacated. If anyone finds a more optimum solution, it would reaaaally help me :)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById('iconCanvas');//<canvas id="iconCanvas" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imgObj=new Image();
    imgObj.src='/images/temp/kdmconfig.png';
    var iconWidth=128;
    var iconHeight=128;
    var width=200;
    var height=128;
    var angleToRotate=30;


    $(imgObj).load(function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        var rad = angleToRotate * Math.PI / 180;
        var newAngle=angleToRotate;

        //in case angle is >90
        if(newAngle>90 && newAngle<=180){
            newAngle=180-newAngle;
        }
        else if(newAngle>180 && newAngle<=270){
            newAngle=270-newAngle;
        }
        else if(newAngle>270){
            newAngle=360-newAngle;
        }

        context.translate(0 + iconWidth / 2, 0 + iconWidth / 2);

        context.rotate(rad);

        //draw the image

        if(width>height){
            var newImageHeight=Math.round((Math.cos((Math.atan(iconWidth/iconHeight)*180/Math.PI)*Math.PI/180)*height)/Math.sin((parseInt(90-newAngle)+Math.atan(iconWidth/iconHeight)*180/Math.PI)*Math.PI/180));

            var newImageWidth=Math.round(newImageHeight*iconWidth/iconHeight);
        }
        else{
            var newImageWidth=Math.round((Math.cos((Math.atan(iconHeight/iconWidth)*180/Math.PI)*Math.PI/180)*width)/Math.sin((parseInt(90-newAngle)+Math.atan(iconHeight/iconWidth)*180/Math.PI)*Math.PI/180));

            var newImageHeight=Math.round(newImageWidth*iconHeight/iconWidth);
        }


        context.drawImage(imgObj,newImageWidth / 2 * (-1),newImageHeight / 2 * (-1),newImageWidth,newImageHeight);

    });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
newCanvas.height="175";
newCanvas.width="175";
newCanvas.style.border="1px solid black";
document.body.appendChild(newCanvas);

var imgObj=new Image();
imgObj.src='people.jpg';
var width=imgObj.width;
var height=imgObj.height;

var angleToRotate = 30 * Math.PI / 180;

var requiredCanvasHeight = Math.sin(angleToRotate)*width+Math.cos(angleToRotate)*height;
var requiredCanvasWidth = Math.sin(angleToRotate)*height+Math.cos(angleToRotate)*width;
newCanvas.height=Math.ceil(requiredCanvasHeight);
newCanvas.width=Math.ceil(requiredCanvasWidth);

$(imgObj).load(function() {
    var context = newCanvas.getContext('2d');

    context.clearRect(0, 0, newCanvas.width, newCanvas.height);

    context.translate(0 + width / 2, 0);// + height / 2);

    context.rotate(angleToRotate);

    //draw the image    
    context.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, width, height);

    //reset the canvas  
    context.rotate(rad * ( -1 ) );
    context.translate((0 + width / 2) * (-1), (0 + height / 2) * (-1));
});
```

You need not offset the image in drawImage method call.

Comment: Nope. that's not what I want. I need the image to be resized automatically to fit the canvas rectangle in case the rotated image size is smaller than the canvas size. The rotation itself is fine. It places the image correctly. It just doesn't resize it the way it should.

Comment: For that you can use trigonometry to do the calculations. Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/poonia/3tPsc/

Comment: This one is nice, thank you. BUT - it's still not what I need. First of all - it doesn't work for other angles other than 30 (i tried 45 and 60). Second - the given formula increases the size of the canvas, while I need the image inside to be resized to fit the canvas. And the canvas does not have to be the size of the original image. It may be smaller and it's fixed.